# typescript proto files not generating

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I am able to generate JS and golang protobuf files, but not typescript. I keep getting an error that reads.

```
protoc-gen-ts: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Plugin failed with status code 1.
make: *** [proto-old] Error 1
```

package.json deps

```
"grpc-mp": "^1.0.1",
"grpc-tools": "^1.11.3",
"grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.2",
"ts-proto": "^1.131.0",
"ts-protoc-gen": "^0.15.0",
"vscode-ws-jsonrpc": "^2.0.0",
```

command

```
protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto \
      --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${PROJ_PATH}/view/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin \
      --js_out=import_style=commonjs:${PROJ_PATH}/view/proto \
      --plugin=${PROJ_PATH}/view/node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto \
      --ts_proto_out=${PROJ_PATH}/view/proto \
      --ts_out=${PROJ_PATH}/view/proto
```

Oddly, the JS files generated **do not** did not generate a client server. However, I would rather use typescript in combination with vue.js. As for the backend server I am using GO, and it did generate the server connection code. Hopefully once the typescript generation works the code to create the client server will be generated.

Question:

What is wrong with my proto command? The plugin is there and it appears to be inline with the docs.

Advice?

---- update 1 ----

had a small typo, here is the update

```
protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto \
      --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${PROJ_PATH}/form/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin \
      --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto \
      --ts_out=service=grpc-web:${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto \
      --js_out=import_style=commonjs:${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto
```

error:

```
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

For some reason I TS code will not generate. My goal is for the vue.js frontend to communicate with my go backend. I am only working with the directory "form" and "api" at the moment.

Comment: The improbable-eng [`ts-protoc-gen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-protoc-gen) plugin is called `protoc-gen-ts` **not** `protoc-gen_ts_proto`. The instructions provide an [example](https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen#generating-typescript-definitions-for-commonjs-modules-generated-by-protoc),

Comment: @DazWilkin you are correct. However I still have the same error with... ```--plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \```... Thank you for taking the time to post.------------  ```` ./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--ts_out: protoc-gen-ts: Plugin failed with status code 1.
make: *** [proto-old] Error 1````

Comment: Is `protoc-gen-ts` in `./node_modules/.bin`? Is it executable? For me `./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts` is a link to `./node_modules/ts-protoc-gen/bin/protoc-gen-ts`.

Comment: @DazWilkin I am not sure if I understand the question.  `ls -all | grep proto` gives me the same permissions  for every file `drwxr-xr-x `. Sorry if I did not understand it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from scratch:

Install protoc:

```bash
VERS="21.9"
ARCH="linux-x86_64"

ENDPOINT="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download"

wget ${ENDPOINT}/v${VERS}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}.zip \
-O ${PWD}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}.zip && \
unzip \
  protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}.zip \
  -d ${PWD}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH} && \
rm ${PWD}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}.zip

PATH=${PATH}:${PWD}/protoc-${VERS}-${ARCH}/bin
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "74275480",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-protoc-gen": "^0.15.0"
  }
}
```

Create NPM project:

```bash
npm install
```

```bash
PROTO="api.proto"

protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--plugin="protoc-gen-ts"=${PWD}/node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \
--ts_out=${PWD} \
 ${PWD}/${PROTO}
```

Then:

```bash
api_pb.d.ts # Output
api.proto
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
protoc-21.9-linux-x86_64
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it working with your example.

Comment: I can only get this to work **if** I first install `ts-proto` globally with `npm i -g ts-proto`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some of the devDependencies, try this one:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@protobuf-ts/protoc": "^2.8.1",
  "@types/google-protobuf": "^3.15.6",
  "google-protobuf": "^3.21.0",
  "protoc-gen-ts": "^0.8.5",
  "protoc-gen-grpc": "^2.0.3"
}
```

Comment: still have the same issue sady

Comment: I updated my comment again with the project link